# Authority not strictly under a public suffix - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm setting up OAuth2 on my development machine for one of my websites. I've been using single  host cookie policy at first, but the website I'm currently working on has several domains attached to it on the IIS - could that by any chance be interfering?

I've tried setting the cookie policy to

`"data-cookiepolicy="http://myhost.c.d"`

which supposedly should allow anything within that domain, such as http://mywebsite.myhost.c.d, and yet when I try to authenticate I get the pop up with

`Authority not strictly under a public suffix: myhost.c.d`

Has anyone experienced and solved this? I feel like it's something clear that I'm missing out on